# messagebox always pop up when clicking combo box

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day, anyone can help me with this problem... I have a combo box and a textbox. the textbox(txtFruitNo) will check the length of text under `Leave` event. It is ok. But if I click on the combo box while txtFruitNo is not yet completed. It needs me to complete first the length of txtFruitNo then only I can click the combo box.

I do not want to show the messagebox if I click on the combo box even if the length of the txtFruitNo is not yet completed.

Thanks

```
private void cmbFruitSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime thetime = DateTime.Now;
        String varApple = "App-Red";
        String varBanana = "Ban-Yellow";

        if (cmbFruitSelection.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Apple")
        {
            txtFruitNo.Text = varApple.ToString() + thetime.ToString("yyyy");
            txtFruitNo.SelectionStart = txtFruitNo.Text.Length;
            txtFruitNo.MaxLength = 18;

        }
        else if (cmbFruitSelection.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Banana")
        {
            txtFruitNo.Text = varBanana.ToString() + thetime.ToString("yyyy");
            txtFruitNo.SelectionStart = txtFruitNo.Text.Length;
            txtFruitNo.MaxLength = 17;

        }
    }

    private void txtFruitNo_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFruitNo.TextLength != txtFruitNo.MaxLength)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your fruit number is too short. Please check.");
            txtFruitNo.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would be able to achieve the desired by introducing a custom property indicating that the Combo was clicked. And check if the custom `property = true` before prompting the message.

Comment: @fujiFX. do you have code there.... it really helps

Comment: Use the Validating event instead.  You can set e.Cancel = true to prevent the user from changing the focus.  Use ErrorProvider to avoid slapping the user with a message box.

Comment: @HansPassant. Do you have code there, I'd never tried ErrorProvider before. But now I'm searching here in SO and other websites. But to be short can you show me how it is done...

Comment: @jLaw; Please check my answer below, hope it helps you to address your need

Answer (score 0):

At what point is it important for continuation of the program that the "Fruit Number" is within parameters. If it is not at the time of leaving focus try moving it to a different control for example the "OK" button could run the parameter check and if valid continue if not flag mesage box and return to the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is to only to do the validation and prompt the message box once the user has selected a value from the combo, please do the following;

Introduce a form variable

```
private bool isComboClicked = false;
```

Add the below line to `cmbFruitSelection_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
isComboClicked = true;
```

Adding the above line at the beginning of the above event would prompt the length validation message on selection of value from the combo. If you want to prompt message for specific value on the combo move it within the if statements `if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Apple")` etc.

Now in `txtFruitNo_Leave` event enclose the code within the below if condition.

```
if (isComboClicked)
{
    // Your Code
    if (txtFruitNo.TextLength != txtFruitNo.MaxLength)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your fruit number is too short. Please check.");
                txtFruitNo.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something here
            }
}
```

Comment: To Down voter: appreciate if left a comment with the reason behind the down vote. This would help me to improve this/ future answer(s).

Comment: I am downvoter, `txtFruitNo_Leave` eventhandler will never validate text, because `isComboClicked` will be always false, until user change index. Consider case where user start typing in the TextBox first, then within incomplete text will try to set valid text through ComboBox control.

Comment: @Fabio, thank you for the feedback. But isn't that what OP wants? May be that's how understood when went through his description.

Comment: In question: _I do not want to show the messagebox if I click on the combo box even if the length of the txtFruitNo is not yet completed._  But in your code messageBox will be showed even value was set through combobox. And if user write incomplete text and press some "Save" button or close form, no validation will happened.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand:
You have "validation" on `TextBox` in `Leave` eventhandler, which show error message if validation fails.
But if `TextBox.Leave` event was raised by selecting `ComboBox` control, then validation must be suppressed.

Create `Panel` and put there only `txtFruitNo` and `cmbFruitSelection` controls.

```cs
// Validation function
private bool IsTextBoxValid()
{
    return this.txtFruitNo.Length == this.txtFruitNo.maxlength;
}
```

Then create and hook up `Validating` eventhandler for `Panel` where you will validate `txtFruitNo`

```cs
private void Panel_Validating(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.IsTextBoxValid() == false)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Your fruit number is too short. Please check.") ;          
    }
}
```

Validating will be raised only when focus move outside of the panel.
Using `Validating` event will prevent changing focus to outside controls automatically if `e.Cancel = true`
In that case combobox `cmbFruitSelection` can be focused and user can complete `txtFruitNo` text by selecting valid value from ComboBox.

I think using of `ErrorProvider` control will be more friendly for the user, then `MessageBox`.
Add `ErrorProvider` control in the `Form` through designer and add few lines in the code

```cs
private void Panel_Validating(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.IsTextBoxValid() == false)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtFruitNo, 
                                     "Your fruit number is too short. Please check.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.ErrorProvider1.Clear();
    }
}
```

And clear error after valid value was used from `ComboBox`

```cs
private void cmbFruitSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime thetime = DateTime.Now;
    String varApple = "App-Red";
    String varBanana = "Ban-Yellow";

    if (cmbFruitSelection.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Apple")
    {
        txtFruitNo.Text = varApple.ToString() + thetime.ToString("yyyy");
        txtFruitNo.SelectionStart = txtFruitNo.Text.Length;
        txtFruitNo.MaxLength = 18;
        //Clear error
        this.ErrorProvider1.Clear();
    }
    else if (cmbFruitSelection.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Banana")
    {
        txtFruitNo.Text = varBanana.ToString() + thetime.ToString("yyyy");
        txtFruitNo.SelectionStart = txtFruitNo.Text.Length;
        txtFruitNo.MaxLength = 17;
        //Clear error
        this.ErrorProvider1.Clear();            
    }
}
```